# how to pass different value to backend and show different value in ui on submit in react js?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am new in react js. I am fetching an API where there are two values from the backend
{
id: int,
name: string,
}
I am displaying the same data using the map as radio format as below

```
<FormControl component="fieldset" className={classes5.formControl}>
    <FormLabel component="legend">Document Type</FormLabel>
    <RadioGroup
        key="id"
        aria-label="Document"
        // name="id"
        className={classes5.group}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        //row>
        {docs?.map((x) => 
            (<FormControlLabel
                key={x.id}
                value={x.name}
                control={<Radio />}
                label={x.name} />)
            )
        }
     </RadioGroup>
</FormControl>
```

here handle change is simple

```
const initialValues={id :0}
const [value, setValue] = React.useState({initialValues});
function handleChange(event) {setValue(event.target.value);}
```

I am uploading a file with userid formdata and id and I want to pass the id of the radio button
in id field on update method.

```
const uploadFile = (files) => {
   if (files.length > 0) {
      let formData = new FormData();
      for (var j = 0; j < files.length; j++) {
          formData.append("file", files[j], files[j].name);
      }

      if (isValidFiles(files)) {
          alert('valid');
      } else {
           alert('invalid');
      }

      upload(formData, userId,id).then((response) => {
          if (response) {} else {}
      });
   }
}
```

How can I pass the same as event target value is sending name from API
and event target name is sending id but I am unable to submit that id facing string cant be converted to int and also getting wrong values some time?

Comment: function handleChange(event) {setValue(event.target.name);}

Then send the value to your API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario I want to pass id to backend and want to show name in label.
earlier when I changed the value to id I got null value in values state on submitting the data and also button was not changed to selected. For that I changed radio group as follows

```
<RadioGroup
      key="id"
      aria-label="Document"
      className={classes5.group}
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      row>
      {docs?.map((x) =>
   (<FormControlLabel
       key={x.id}
       value={x.id.toString()}
       control={<Radio />}
       label={x.name} />)
        )}
</RadioGroup>
```

By on click handleChange value was perfectly passed to values. Here I used toString() because when I was passing value the radio button color not turned to selected radio button and yes it worked. If there is any suggestions or need to correct some approach suggestions accepted with regards.